# Fixed elements scrolling in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

We have this weird issue with fixed elements.

We have a site, where we display data in the table. Above the table, we have a fixed header and on the left side of the window, we have a sidebar. Now when sidebar is opened we move table 544 px to the right with tranformX.

Issue is present in next conditions. When width of the table is smaller then window width (no horizontal scrollbar) and then we open sidebar and move table right for 544px, and with that horizontal scrollbar is present now, which is ok. The problem is when we scroll vertically now, because it moves fixed elements up for 47px(height of scrollbars).

Does anyone have any clue, on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Your issue is a little difficult to imagine without some code. Can you create a codepen, or fiddle of your problem? That way we can open it up in IE ourselves.

Comment: I dont think I will be able to create an example, it is a complex site.